# can you explain how this Loop works and how do we get that output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())     
for i in range (0,n):     
 result = i**2      
 print(result)

#input : 5
#output : 0 1 4 9 16
```

range 0,n = 0,1,2,3,4 and
we gave i**2 but how we got 0,1,4,9,16 as output?

Comment: `i**2` means "square of `i`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

range(start, stop, step)

** = square of Number

1. start Optional. An integer number specifying at which position to
   start. Default is 0
2. stop Required. An integer number specifying at which position to
   stop (not included).
3. step Optional. An integer number specifying the incrementation. Default is 1

you are passing required parameter as 5 which will not be included in the loop. so as per your calculation it will start from 0

```
result = 0**2 = 0
result = 1**2 = 1
result = 2**2 = 4
result = 3**2 = 9
result = 4**2 = 16
```

'i' will not reach 5 because of non-inclusive nature of range() operator.